# Draw the plot result in an image and save it as an image in python

Tags: python, image, plot

I want to draw the plot result in an image and save it as an image in python.
I have a method that could Harris method in result there are alot of point that I want to trace in a picture but win I save the figure is giving me just the point not the image also please give me an advice

Answer (score 0):

Use the command `fig.savefig('line plot.jpg', bbox_inches='tight', dpi=150)`